# Radial gradiant, split a section in two CSS ellipse shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to split my section in two, and make the middle into this half ellipse shape. But I can't do it.

[image]

```css
.super {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, red 50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="super">
  <div class="nice">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the result you want but try using the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property.

```css
.super {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 89% 54%);
}
```

```html
<section class="super">
   <div class="nice">
   </div>
 </section>
```

You can generate a custom clip path using a tool like: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
body
{
  background-color:black;
}

#wrapper
{
  width:600px;
  height:175px;
  background-color:#3596fb;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#circle
{
    background-color:white;
    height:600px;
    width:600px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top:-30%;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1kwvuzd/2/